# Materials recommendation request for non-linear optimization with linear constraints

Tags: reference-request, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning

I am looking for academic materials on non-linear optimization - specifically about problems with a non-linear objective function and linear constraints.

I have looked online, but the materials tend to be on non-linear optimization in general and not this specific subset of problems. Does anyone have recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might consider posting on the new [or.se] Stack Exchange site. Also, are you looking for textbook- or tutorial-type materials, or research papers?

Comment: Thank you, Larry. I am looking for a textbook.